# Handling self-closing tags in NSXmlParser?

Tags: ios, xml

How can we can we handle self-closing Tags in NSXmlparser? There is no
starting element and end element -- is it possible to handle the following type of Tags?

```
<ITEM NAME/>
<REG Number/>
```

Comment: use TbXml parsing in this you easly get this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any XML Parser, including NSXMLParser, should be treating this:

```
<ITEMNAME/>
```

identically to this XML:

```
<ITEMNAME></ITEMNAME>
```

In other words, as far as the parser code you write is concerned, you should see both the start and the end of the element callbacks being invoked by the parser. To prove this out, I put the following sample XML in a file:

```
<top>
    <sample1/>
    <sample2 attr1="a"/>
</top>
```

I then implemented the following code to load this file and parse it:

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"xml"];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sampleURL];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

My parser delegate methods were implemented as follows:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Received didStartElement callback for tag: %@", elementName);
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    NSLog(@"Received didEndElement callback for tag: %@", elementName);
}
```

When I ran this code I saw the following console output:

```
2012-01-01 22:24:24.011 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didStartElement callback for tag: top
2012-01-01 22:24:24.012 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didStartElement callback for tag: sample1
2012-01-01 22:24:24.013 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didEndElement callback for tag: sample1
2012-01-01 22:24:24.013 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didStartElement callback for tag: sample2
2012-01-01 22:24:24.015 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didEndElement callback for tag: sample2
2012-01-01 22:24:24.015 SampleXML[10248:707] Received didEndElement callback for tag: top
```

As you can see, I got both a didStartElement and didEndElement callback for both the sample1 and sample2 tags, which is how it should be working.

Comment: parserdidstart and parserdidend element deleagate methods will be called as usually?I checked , it is not called..

Comment: are you sure? I haven't tried it but it seems like only  `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` would be called since `<ITEMNAME/>` is an end tag, right?

Comment: I believe that it is part of the XML 1.0 specification that the two are alternate forms of the same thing as far as any parser is concerned. I'll see if I can verify that. I do know that didStartElement would have to be called for sure if the element has any attributes. I would be surprised if it wasn't called no matter what, but it will take me a bit to verify that.

Comment: I just threw together a sample app and it worked as I expected: Both the didStartElement and didElement callbacks were received. I'll update my response to provide an example with output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the end tag and it will call the `didEndElement` of the `NSXMLParser` delegate.

The found characters for this tag will be empty.

There is no need for any special logic to handle this.v

Comment: is correct that there is no need for any special logic to handle this. It may not be entirely accurate to say that the found characters will be empty. When using XML's "empty element" syntax like this the NSXMLParserDelegate's foundCharacters callback will never be called. Also, it is not accurate to say that "this is the end tag" - This is special XML syntax that is shorthand for both the start and the end tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a xml parser and one of my tags was empty and self enclosing  ie

start and endelement are working ...